# How to fetch rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract rows from database depending on two columns where only one column is indexed (primary key) and other is not .

Example : table A has columns a(PK), b(date feild), c

Now I'm trying to get rows where b = 29-04-2019 and a = 1 , b = 30-04-2019 and a = 2 . In this case i can only get 4 rows 2 rows for a = 1 (both dates) and two rows for a = 2 (both dates) but I need only two rows totally .

I have tried this Query :

```
select * from A 
where a in (1,2) 
and b in ("2019-04-29","2019-04-30")
```

Comment: `... where (a=1 and b = 2019-04-29") or (a=2 and b="2019-04-30")`

Comment: What's the logic for excluding 2 rows? Sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: a and b is
1:12-05-2019
1:11-05-2019
1:10-05-2019
1:09-05-2019
1:08-05-2019
1:07-05-2019
1:06-05-2019
1:12-05-2019
1:11-05-2019
1:10-05-2019
2:12-05-2019
2:12-05-2019
2:11-05-2019
2:11-05-2019
2:10-05-2019
2:09-05-2019
2:08-05-2019
2:07-05-2019
2:07-05-2019
2:06-05-2019 . here i need rows of a with date "12-05-2019 or 10-05-2019" and rows of b with dates "09-05-2019 or 07-05-2019" . Now I'm using select * from A 
where a in (1,2) and b between "07-05-2019" and "12-05-2019"

Answer (score 0):

You need the SELECT using WHERE with OR operator.

Typical example is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE condition1
OR condition2;
```

This will select all matching rows where EITHER *condition1* is true, OR *condition2* is true.

So in your case:

- *condition1* is `a = 1 AND b = "2019-04-29"`
- *condition2* is `a = 2 AND b = "2019-04-30"`

Putting it together:

```
SELECT * from A 
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = "2019-04-29") 
OR (a = 2 AND b = "2019-04-30")
```

Note that if you data has more than 1 instance of each condition, you will return more than 2 rows in total.

Comment: Im having multiple a's and multiple b's with respect to each a's

Comment: Can you tell me what's your actual output?

Comment: a and b is 1:12-05-2019 1:11-05-2019 1:10-05-2019 1:09-05-2019 1:08-05-2019 1:07-05-2019 1:06-05-2019 1:12-05-2019 1:11-05-2019 1:10-05-2019 2:12-05-2019 2:12-05-2019 2:11-05-2019 2:11-05-2019 2:10-05-2019 2:09-05-2019 2:08-05-2019 2:07-05-2019 2:07-05-2019 2:06-05-2019 . here i need rows of a with date "12-05-2019 or 10-05-2019" and rows of b with dates "09-05-2019 or 07-05-2019" . Now I'm using select * from A where a in (1,2) and b between "07-05-2019" and "12-05-2019"

Comment: Have you tried using the select in my answer?? `SELECT * from A 
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = "2019-04-29") OR (a = 2 AND b = "2019-04-30")` This is very different from yours.

Comment: I'm having thousands of a and for each a lakhs of b

Comment: i might need to do a lot of operations